# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: java, api, web-service, tomcat

Eai galera, tranquilo?
Então estou com um problema na execução do meu WS, desenvolvi em java, na hora de iniciar ele me retorna esse erro junto com:

```
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

30-Apr-2019 07:59:29.771 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 13 more
```

Tem idéia do que possa ser?

Comment: Coloque o código de configuração do seu WS, aonde você define a porta de uso.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: Consegui sim, acabei esquecendo de atualizar aqui, o problema era que quando eu pegava meu projeto do git fazendo um clone pro netbeans ele bugava meu filtro, dai removi o mesmo e adicionei de novo, por algum motivo o tomcat não respeitava o filtro que tinha. obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Se a resposta dada ajudou você a resolver o problema, marque-a como resposta certa. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Bom, o erro está dizendo que o endereço do WS que você está tentando utilizar já está em uso. Verifique a sua configuração e adicione uma porta livre.

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 13 more
```